# C# Line by Line check of a file

Tags: c#, file-io, line-by-line

I am reading from a file line by line and i want to edit some of the lines i read.. 
The lines i want to edit must have some other specific lines above or below them, but i dont know how to express that in C#. 
For example:

```
http://www.youtube.com
You Tube | Music | something
Sports
Music
Radio
Clips
http://www.youtube.com/EDIT ME   
Sports
Music
Radio
Clips
```

and i want to edit a line 
only if next line is

```
Sports
```

and the previous line is

```
Clips
```

So the only line i want to edit from the example above is

```
http://www.youtube.com/EDIT ME
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Eh, is your sample data correct? It looks like you copied the first section and didn't edit out the bits you don't want.

Answer (score 6):

You can't really "edit" a file line by line. It would be best to take one of two approaches:

- Read the whole file into memory, e.g. using [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx), then make appropriate changes in memory and rewrite the whole thing (e.g. using [`File.WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3.aspx))
- Open both the input file and output file at the same time. Read a line at a time, work out what it should correspond to in the output file, then write the line.

The first version is simpler, but obviously requires more memory. It's *particularly* tricky if you need to look at the next and previous line, as you mentioned.

Simple example of the first approach:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("foo.txt");
for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (lines[i - 1] == "Clips" && lines[i + 1] == "Sports")
    {
        lines[i] = "Changed";
    }
}
File.WriteAllLines("foo.txt", lines);
```

Answer (score 2):

*Approach #1*
While you're looping through the file, keep a variable for the the previous line (always update this to the current line before you loop). Now you know the current line and previous line, you can decide if you need to edit the current line.

*Approach #2*
While you're looping through the file, set a flag corresponding to some condition e.g. I've just found `Sports`. If you later find a condition that should unset the flag e.g. I've just found `Radio`, un set it. If you find `Clips` you can check is the `SportsFlag` set to see if you need to edit this `Clips` line.

The second approach is more flexible (allows you to set and unset multiple flags depending on the current line) and and is good if there could be multiple lines of crud between `Sports` and `Clips`. It's effectively a poor mans [State Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_machine)

Answer (score 1):

If the file isn't that large, I would read in the entire file as a string. Then you can freely manipulate it using methods like indexOf and substring.

Once you have the string how you need it, write it back over the file you had.